# amp-audio problem in loading mp3 file completely

Tags: networking, mp3, amp-html

I'm currently facing an issue with AMP-audio.
When i open the page that has an mp3 file it works for the first 5 mints and then it go to the end of the mp3 file directly.

i'm wondering, is there any thing that i can do to prevent that, or this is a network issue?

- my code is like this

  ```
  <amp-audio width="auto"
             height="50"
             src="1.mp3"
             preload="auto"
             autoplay
             controlsList="nodownload">
              <div fallback>
                   <p>Your browser doesn’t support HTML5 audio</p>
              </div>
  </amp-audio>
  ```

  Thanks in advance .

Comment: This is almost certainly an issue with the MP3 file itself. The best solution is to re-encode it.

Comment: The file is correct. re-encode it will don't help in this case i think.